# Unable to change App Icon under notification area on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, icons

I'm able to change the app icon from app shortcut properties.

[image: screenshot]

But the icon doesn't' change under notification icons.

[image: screenshot]

Why is that the icon isn't changing under notification center icons? Is there a way to change the notification center icon as well?

Comment: The icon displayed in the taskbar is configured by the executable. The icon showed for a shortcut isn’t.

Comment: I managed to change the exe icon using resource hacker but  after launching the app the ICON remains the same.

Comment: You made no mention of Resource Hacker. Your screenshot is only that of a shortcut, which can have any icon you want, since it's not an executable with an embedded resource and that of Taskbar which uses the embedded resource as per the executable if it exists and was programmed to use it.

Comment: An executable may contain more than one icon. You need to change all of them.